# How do the Mechanical Properties of 3D Printed Metal Parts Compare to Parts Made by Investment Casting?

Tags: print-quality

I have read quite a few articles discussing various issues with 3D printed metal parts, a few are listed below. (Ref 1 thru 4)  However, I was not able to find any sources of information quantitatively comparing 3D printed metal parts to similar parts created by investment casting.  I'm interested in any quantitative comparison to metal parts made by powder bed fusion, direct energy deposition, or binder jet printing.  I'm specifically interested in strength, stiffness, and porosity for 3D printing versus casting.

Ref 1 -
https://www.llnl.gov/news/llnl-finds-reason-behind-defects-3d-printing

Ref 2 -
https://amfg.ai/2018/05/01/5-problems-faced-when-3d-printing-metals-and-how-to-fix-them/

Ref 3 -
https://all3dp.com/4/researchers-detect-defects-metal-3d-printed-parts-using-neural-networks/

Ref 4 - https://insights.globalspec.com/article/7458/how-strong-are-3d-printed-metal-parts-metallurgical-integrity-in-metal-additive-manufacturing